# SQLite file from assets not getting updated after inserting a record

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to insert a record in my database but it's not updating my database.

My insert method:

```
public void insert(String name, String status, String seat, String  id, String pnr) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_ID, id);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_PNR, pnr);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_STATUS, status);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_SEAT_NO, seat);

    database.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}
```

Code when inserting:

```
dbManager = new DBManager(getContext());
dbManager.open();
dbManager.insert("Name","XYZ","B1 21", "2","2348384");
```

open method:

```
public DBManager open() throws SQLException {
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context) {};
    database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

I am using SQLite Asset Helper in my DatabaseHelper and the database is stored in assests/databases

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assets* folder is meant for read-only purposes. You cannot alter the contents at run time - except build/development time.

In your case, I would suggest you to copy the database file from assets to your app's private folder (or your desired location) on SD/external storage and then use that database file to perform read/write operations.

In short, your assets' database is good for read operations only.

Note: same rules applies to *Raw* resources too and they serve a slightly different purpose.

Comment: How to do that using SQLiteAssetHelper? Please share an example. Thanks

Comment: rely on something like `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), null, DATABASE_VERSION);` in the constructor - which copies the database file to external storage

Comment: Read the repo's documentation. You'll find more details outlined there